# How to handle file explorer dialog box in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to automate a scenario where I am trying to import a file from my local machine to my application. I am doing the import using the SendKeys method but the issue is that
while importing I have to click on the import button as it triggers the user authentication event. But doing so is also opening up the File Explorer dialog in the background which I do not know how to close. Is there a way to close the explorer? AutoIt is not supported by my framework as I am using.NetCore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

This can be done by using the Process class provided by C#.